# Python encoding for space character

Tags: python, encoding

I was writing a function that changes all spaces in the string with the character § and then splits all characters in a string with space.
I have written a function like as follows:

```
def createList(text):
sentence = ""
for char in text:
    if char == " ":
        sentence = sentence + "§ "
    else:
        sentence = sentence + char
myFile = open("ahoi.txt", "w")
myFile.write(sentence)
myFile.close()
return sentence
```

The problem here is my input is not unicode so I don't change my inputs encoding and do the process. Then when I try to add spaces like as follows:

```
def createList(text):
sentence = ""
for char in text:
    if char == " ":
        sentence = sentence + "§ "
    else:
        sentence = sentence + char + " "
myFile = open("ahoi.txt", "w")
myFile.write(sentence)
myFile.close()
return sentence
```

All characters are broken. My input include some characters like ş , ı, ü, ö. So I mustn't lose them. What kind of encoding and decoding should I do? I have tried many solutions but none of them worked.

Here is a sample input:

a = """Bunları söyledikten sonra, şiltenin altından bir mektup çıkardı.
Ancak, bu kırlangıçlar çok küçüktürler ve o kadar hızlı uçarlar ki, şelaleyi bir ok gibi keserek arka tarafına geçebilirler.
Şuracıkta, senin yanında yatıveririm ben."
Yardım etmek isterdim, ama burnumu sokmasam daha iyi olur.
İşinin ilk gününde bir öğrencinin ağır yaralanmasının, sonra da kendi dispanserinde ölmesinin beklenilmezliği uykuda gezmesi sonucunu doğurmuş olmalıydı.
Önünde ejderhalardan daha beter bir şey olamazdı, değil mi?
Sorusunun bir nedeni olmalı, diye düşünüyordu."""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

def createList(text):
    sentence = ""
    for char in text:
        if char == " ":
            sentence = sentence + u"§ "
        else:
            sentence = sentence + char + " "
    myFile = open("ahoi.txt", "w")
    myFile.write(sentence.encode("utf-8"))
    myFile.close()
    return sentence


a = u"""Bunları söyledikten sonra, şiltenin altından bir mektup çıkardı. Ancak, bu kırlangıçlar çok küçüktürler ve o kadar hızlı uçarlar ki, şelaleyi bir ok gibi keserek arka tarafına geçebilirler. Şuracıkta, senin yanında yatıveririm ben." Yardım etmek isterdim, ama burnumu sokmasam daha iyi olur. İşinin ilk gününde bir öğrencinin ağır yaralanmasının, sonra da kendi dispanserinde ölmesinin beklenilmezliği uykuda gezmesi sonucunu doğurmuş olmalıydı. Önünde ejderhalardan daha beter bir şey olamazdı, değil mi? Sorusunun bir nedeni olmalı, diye düşünüyordu."""

print createList(a)
```

Output:

```
B u n l a r ı § s ö y l e d i k t e n § s o n r a , § ş i l t e n i n § a l t ı n d a n § b i r § m e k t u p § ç ı k a r d ı . § A n c a k , § b u § k ı r l a n g ı ç l a r § ç o k § k ü ç ü k t ü r l e r § v e § o § k a d a r § h ı z l ı § u ç a r l a r § k i , § ş e l a l e y i § b i r § o k § g i b i § k e s e r e k § a r k a § t a r a f ı n a § g e ç e b i l i r l e r . § Ş u r a c ı k t a , § s e n i n § y a n ı n d a § y a t ı v e r i r i m § b e n . " § Y a r d ı m § e t m e k § i s t e r d i m , § a m a § b u r n u m u § s o k m a s a m § d a h a § i y i § o l u r . § İ ş i n i n § i l k § g ü n ü n d e § b i r § ö ğ r e n c i n i n § a ğ ı r § y a r a l a n m a s ı n ı n , § s o n r a § d a § k e n d i § d i s p a n s e r i n d e § ö l m e s i n i n § b e k l e n i l m e z l i ğ i § u y k u d a § g e z m e s i § s o n u c u n u § d o ğ u r m u ş § o l m a l ı y d ı . § Ö n ü n d e § e j d e r h a l a r d a n § d a h a § b e t e r § b i r § ş e y § o l a m a z d ı , § d e ğ i l § m i ? § S o r u s u n u n § b i r § n e d e n i § o l m a l ı , § d i y e § d ü ş ü n ü y o r d u .
```